# React, performances difference with className inline or in const

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-native

I have a React app with a lot of items in list.

I'm just wondering if there is any performance difference with this two approaches:

**- 1 - List with const className:**

```
{items.map(item => {
    const trClassname = item.type === 1 ? "red" : "green";
    return (
        <tr className={trClassname}>{item.name + " - " + item.type}</tr>
    );
})}
```

**- 2 - List with inline className:**

```
{items.map(item => {
    return (
    <tr className={item.type === 1 ? "red" : "green"}>
        {item.name + " - " + item.type}
    </tr>
    );
})}
```

You can see **reproduction here**: https://codesandbox.io/s/mjl43x38j9

Comment: Whatever performance difference there is it will be negligible.

Comment: @Tholle, Yes, but in the first one I have const every time. In the second no. It's the same?

Comment: The second option will most likely be negligibly faster.

Comment: Is there another (maybe faster) way to do it?

Comment: Variable performance impact is minimal. If it's needed for readability, use it.

Comment: The second example is most likely as fast as you can get it, but you don't have to worry about negligible performance gains at this level. Whatever difference there are, it will not make a noticeable difference in your app. I think you should focus on creating readable code instead.

Comment: You are doing premature optimization. Instead of worring about const creation cost you should better think how to reduce the amount of items to display ("app with a lot of items in list").

Comment: Ok. Thanks to all, but still... Is there another (maybe faster) way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Written as is, should behave exactly the same, if we are talking of render performances beacause the same operation (case 1 and 2) is repeated for every element the same amount of times.

Comment: Yes, but in the first one I have `const` every time. In the second no. It's the same?

Comment: you cant try to monitor the performance of both codes in chrome. As I can see they have the same performance as the performance are consumed mostly on comparison and rendering and both happens at the same time and require the same amount of cpu for both code snippets.

Comment: and what about memory with all that `const`s?